# Demography vs. political preference data sources

Tags: data-request, government, europe, census

I am looking for data on the relationship between demography (mainly indicators of knowledge such as formal education, rural/urban residency, salary) and political preference, preferably in the UK or the EU as a whole.

My aim is to demonstrate the correlation between these two and model potential election outcomes should the suffrage be limited.

Could you please suggest any?

Answer (score 7):

Two resources you might consider are:

- The [European Social Survey](http://www.europeansocialsurvey.org/)
- The [Comparative Study of Electoral Systems](http://www.cses.org/)

Comment: If you plan to use European Social Survey as well as happen to use R for this, then you may find the following related information useful: 1. http://www.r-bloggers.com/analyze-the-european-social-survey-ess-with-r
2. http://www.jstatsoft.org/v57/i01/paper

Comment: Could you please detail what each dataset contain? It would be better than a links-only answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Check this collection of static and real-time data sets: http://www.oecd.org/statistics. Most indicators should be on a per-country (including per-EU-country) basis.

Also, see:

- http://data.worldbank.org and http://data.worldbank.org/products/wdi
  (for R there is WDI package)
- http://data.un.org/DataMartInfo.aspx
- http://www.google.com/publicdata/directory

Answer (score 3):

The [European Values Study](http://www.europeanvaluesstudy.eu/) provides this information. The microdata is freely available.

You can consider it as a substitute to the [European Social Survey](http://www.europeansocialsurvey.org/) mentioned in this same thread. Or as a complement, if you want to check the robustness of your findings.